# Astro adapter with Netlify on-demand builder not caching

Tags: caching, netlify, astrojs

After some research I undestood that it is possibile to deploy a website with Astro on Netlify with Server Side Rendering.

Reading the documentation it seems it is also possible to use Netlify On-Demand builder to build pages on demand and then cache them on the CDN.

I tried to implement this feature but it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody knows why?

Here is my code:

```js
// astro.config.mjs

import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import netlify from "@astrojs/netlify/functions";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  output: "server",
  adapter: netlify({
    builders: true,
  })
});
```

```ini
# netlify.toml

[build]
  command = "yarn build"
  publish = "dist"
```

```js
// src/pages/index.astro

---
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";

const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(7);
  }, 2000)
});
---

<Layout title="Welcome to Astro">
  <main>MAIN {response}</main>
</Layout>
```

The `setTimeout` is for emulating an `async` method that takes some times.

After deploying with:

```
ntl deploy --prod
```

I see the page waiting 2 seconds before delivering the HTML.

However I would expect the Netlify On-Demand Builder to cache it and then not wait 2 seconds anymore.

What am I doing it wrong?